# Calculate last date of the month from a period

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a periods like `012015`, `022015`, `032015` etc.,

Here first 2 chars are `Month` and last four chars are `Year`.

My result should be

`20150131`, `20150228`, `20150331` which is nothing but last date of that month.

Can you help me with this in SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do It in following:

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
CREATE TABLE #dates
(
    Period NVARCHAR(40)
)
INSERT INTO #dates VALUES ('012015'),('022015'),('032015')
```

**QUERY**

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,1+DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,CAST((CAST(RIGHT(Period,4) AS INT) * 100 + CAST(LEFT(Period,2) AS INT)) * 100 + 01 AS NVARCHAR(20))),-1)    
FROM #dates
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Input   Output
012015  2015-01-31 00:00:00.000
022015  2015-02-28 00:00:00.000
032015  2015-03-31 00:00:00.000
```

---

**UPDATE**

Or you can use `REPLACE` to get output as you expected:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CAST(DATEADD(MONTH,1+DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,CAST((CAST(RIGHT(Period,4) AS INT) * 100 + CAST(LEFT(Period,2) AS INT)) * 100 + 01 AS NVARCHAR(20))),-1) AS DATE),'-','')
```

**OUTPUT AFTER UPDATE**

```
Input   Output
012015  20150131
022015  20150228
032015  20150331
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

With your provided data working as expected.

```
CREATE TABLE #dates
(
    Period NVARCHAR(40)
)
INSERT INTO #dates VALUES ('022019'),('022019'),('022019'),('022019'),('112018'),('082019'),('082019'),('082019'),('082019'),('112018'),('112018'),('112018'),('082019'),('022019'),('022019'),('022019'),('022019'),('052016'),('052016'), ('122016')

SELECT  Period as Input,
        REPLACE(CAST(DATEADD(MONTH,1+DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,CAST((CAST(RIGHT(Period,4) AS INT) * 100 + CAST(LEFT(Period,2) AS INT)) * 100 + 01 AS NVARCHAR(20))),-1) AS DATE),'-','') as [Output]
FROM #dates
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Input   Output
022019  20190228
022019  20190228
022019  20190228
022019  20190228
112018  20181130
082019  20190831
082019  20190831
082019  20190831
082019  20190831
112018  20181130
112018  20181130
112018  20181130
082019  20190831
022019  20190228
022019  20190228
022019  20190228
022019  20190228
052016  20160531
052016  20160531
122016  20161231
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Result was what I expected.

Comment: Hi When I ran your query from a table picking period , first 10 rows are converted but for 11th row  I am getting the error "The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value." Do you have any idea? the row value is "022019"

Comment: I tried to remove 11th row and run my query but I am getting the same error

Comment: @vijaykumar Provide all rows which you trying to convert,

Comment: Looks like that you have incorrect value, for example `132015`, It can't be converted because there is no 13th month.

Comment: I don't have row value as 132015 it was 022019. Below are my table values 022019
022019
022019
022019
112018
082019
082019
082019
082019
112018
112018
112018
082019
022019
022019
022019
022019
052016
052016
122016

Comment: There is no error with your sample data, updated my answer.

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas Could you please explain -1 in the dateadd function (as the third argument)?  Why does it subtract 1 day from the date.

Comment: @Crabster when we use `DATEDIFF` with start date `0` It starts count from `1900-01-01`, so when we use datepart `month` It return number of months for selected date. Then we use `DATEADD` to add that number to timestamp -1 to get last day of previous month.

Comment: Thanks @StanislovasKalašnikovas. I was referring to the part where you were subtracting 1 from the date. I didnt know that one could do that with `datetime`. Turns out you can do this: `datetime` + i, where i being any int, and that many number of days would be added/subtracted from the date

Answer (score 0):

Wish it helps,

`CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8), DATEADD(DAY, -1,SUBSTRING('012015', 3, 5) + SUBSTRING('012015', 0, 3) + '01'), 112)`

change the hardcoded date with the date you want to parse.

Good luck!

Comment: Result shows '20141231' but it should be '20150131'

Answer (score 0):

SQL 2012+

try **[EOMONTH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh213020.aspx)**

```
select EOMONTH(yourdate_)
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the last day of each month is a bit difficult (varying from a month to another, considering leap years, etc.).

You can calculate the first date of the next month:

```
myDate = '01/02/2015'
```

and then find the last day of the preceding month subtracting 1 to that date:

```
myDate = DateAdd(date, -1, myDate)
```

The result will be:

```
'31/01/2015'
```

Answer (score 0):

getting the last day of the month is not so hard :

```
select dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, 1, dateadd(day, -datepart(day, getdate()) + 1, getdate())))
```

what is does is simple:
get the day part, and subtract it from the date so you get on the first day of the month
now add one month
now subtract one day

almost forgot, to display the date in the format requested you can do this:
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), getdate(), 112)
done